Is there a way to set the credentials for an SPN to authorise an API request in Python, using a workload identity federation instead of client secret?
I have some Python code that was using the ClientSecretCredential() to authenticate its API requests to Azure but now we are moving to use a workload identity federation instead is there an alternative function I can use for this?
I have tried looking for alternatives to this here but have found none referning to WIF.
The original line of code I'm trying to adjust is:
credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id = args.tenant, client_id = args.client_id, client_secret = args.client_secret)


Query on WIF authentication in Python rather than Azure DevOps
According to the document that you shared, WorkloadIdentityCredential supports Microsoft Entra Workload ID on Kubernetes. How was your function designed to authenticate against WIF and if it ran in Kubernetes environment? Have you tried this sample by the way?
